# Showing hidden column in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble finding how to "show" a hidden column in another sheet with VBA.I am currently studying VBA and I wanted to have a hide/unhide code for every case, but this one is missing. Any suggestions?

My (updated) code is here:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'To Hide Sheet 2
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = False

    'To Hide Rows 22 to 25
    Rows("22:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    'To Hide Columns E to G
    Columns(":G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    'More specific hidding (inside a different sheet)
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns("A:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub

Public Sub UnHideAll()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Rows.Hidden = False
        Columns.Hidden = False
    Next ws

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    UnHideAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Sub UnHideAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ws.Rows.Hidden = False
        ws.Columns.Hidden = False
    Next ws
End Sub
```

The point of the code is that you need to qualify `Rows` and `Columns` by the worksheet if you want them to refer to anything other than the active sheet. Prefixing them by `ws.` lets VBA know what sheet the rows and columns are on. Then in the code for the button just:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UnHideAll
End Sub
```

I've tested it a number of times using both manually columns, rows, and sheets, as well as when it was VBA doing the hiding, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Did the same as the original code. It showed hidden rows, but only from sheet 1.

Comment: @jonathan9879 For me the above code works fine. I can't imagine why it would only effect 1 sheet.

Comment: Note that in your updated code you still just have `Rows.Hidden` and `Columns.Hidden`. Since you don't qualify `Rows` and `Columns` they are interpreted as being in the active sheet, even if it is in the loop like that. I'll edit my post to emphasize this.

Comment: That fixed everything. Thanks for your patients, you where very helpful!